# Having a problem with reading a file using NSString initWithContents OfFile

Tags: cocoa-touch, iphone-sdk-3.0, nsstring

In this program when I debug, it is showing the nil for fileNameString. I could not understand what is the problem. Please help me ?

```
@implementation fromFileRead1
NSString *fileNameString;

-(id)init
{
    if( (self = [super init]) ) 
    {
        fileNameString = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfFile: @"enemyDetails.rtf" encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
        NSArray *lines = [fileNameString componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"]; 
        for (id *line in lines)
        {
            NSLog(@"Line1%@", line );
        }
    }
    return self;
}
@end
```

Thank You.

---

```
-(id)init
{
    if( (self = [super init]) ) 
    {
        NSString *path = @"/Users/sridhar/Desktop/Projects/exampleOnFile2/enemyDetals.txt";
        NSString *contentsOfFile = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
        NSArray *lines = [contentsOfFile componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"]; 
        for (id *line in lines)
        {
            NSLog(@"Line1%@", line );
        }
    }
    return self;
}
@end
```

Comment: I did in the other way. I got what I needed. But what is wrong in the previous method. Please suggest. Can we use it or not ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to specify the full path to the file with string so the problem must be with this part:

```
... initWithContentsOfFile: @"enemyDetails.rtf" ...
```

What exactly path you need depends on where you store your text file. If it is a resource in your bundle you can get the path using `-pathForResource:` function from `NSBundle`:

```
NSString *fPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"enemyDetails" ofType:@"rtf"];
```

If it is stored in another directory in your applications sandbox - see [Getting Paths to Application Directories](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/FilesandNetworking/FilesandNetworking.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH21-SW6)  section in "Developer Programming Guide" about how to get paths for them.

Comment: Hi
Thank You, I thought the full path is not needed. As, it worked for my .png files I thought it could work for this also.